# Not able to call OnNavigatedFrom method after pressing lock key

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing one app in windows phone. In my app it is necessary to handle lock key press event because I have used Timer. Here is my code

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += Micropphone_Current_Activated;
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated += Micropphone_Current_Deactivated;
        if (_autowizardtimer != null)
        {
            _autowizardtimer.Stop();
            _autowizardtimer.Tick -= _timer_Tick;
            if (_endtimer != null)
            {
                _endtimer.Stop();
                _endtimer.Tick -= _endtimer_Tick;
            }
        }      
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       if (_autowizardtimer != null)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated -= Micropphone_Current_Activated;
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated -= Micropphone_Current_Deactivated;
            _autowizardtimer.Stop();
            _autowizardtimer.Tick -= _timer_Tick;
        }
        if (_endtimer != null)
        {               
            _endtimer.Stop();
            _endtimer.Tick -= _endtimer_Tick;
        }
    }
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, when user press lock key the timer get's pause and after releasing lock key timer get's start. The problem is in `OnNavigatedFrom` method. When I press lock key this method is not calling. I am not getting what is the problem. Can some please tell why this is happening? Or Is there any other way to handle lock key press ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stop the timer when the screen is locked, because your application will automatically be deactivated (unless you've explicitly told the system that you want your application to run under the lock screen).

Still, if you want to detect the moment when the screen is locked or unlocked, you can use the events `Obscured` and `Unobscured` respectively.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206951(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Understandingtheeventsthatoccurwhenthephoneislockedorunlocked

Comment: Hey KooKiz Thank you for reply. I want to check it for Lock key as well as Home key. Is it possible using obscured and Unobscured?

Comment: @Ajay For the home key, just check the `Deactivated` event.

Comment: Deactivated event from app.xaml or from PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated ?

Comment: @Ajay I've always used the one in app.xaml, but according to MSDN they work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the lock key you basically don't navigate from the page, but you're deactivating your app. In your case I would handle this timer in the App.xaml.cs Activated and Deactivated events also.

Please take a look at the Windows Phone Application Lifecycle here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx

Regards,